# Retrieval of image failed

Tags: python, windows-10, python-3.7, urllib

I tried to download these images to a local PC, there is no error, but the downloaded images cannot be opened, what did I do wrong? Image [url](https://szaniterplaza.hu/images/itempic/Grohe_Euroeco_bid%C3%A9_csaptelep_32737_000_32737000.jpg)

```
import urllib.request
import urllib
url = 'https://szaniterplaza.hu/images/itempic/Grohe_Euroeco_bidé_csaptelep_32737_000_32737000.jpg'
url = urllib.parse.quote(url, encoding='utf8', safe = '://')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, './image.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

That image URL is invalid.
Your translated URL is invalid too:

`https://szaniterplaza.hu/images/itempic/Grohe_Euroeco_bid%C3%A9_csaptelep_32743_000_32743000.jpg`

Try it in a browser. I just did.

Perhaps if you gave us the correct URL and the URL you need it transformed *from* we can help with the transformation.

What you have downloaded is just the html you see in the browser, just because you named it image.jpg doesn't make it a jpeg.

There's nothing wrong with your download code (apart from `urlretrieve` being deprecated). It worked for `https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg`.